# Is it possible to add Scan Barcodes with ML Kit to the iOS project via Carthage or manually?

Tags: ios, carthage, google-mlkit

In our iOS project we use Carthage as a dependency manager. And we want to add [Scan Barcodes with ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/ios) to the project. But seems that Scan Barcodes is distributed via Cocoapods only. Is there any way to add `GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning` via Carthage or manually?

Comment: Looks like they aren't even planning on adding support https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/issues/26